# Excel user form and windows.visible

Tags: forms, vba, excel, visible

I need some help finishing this project.

I have created a userform that acts as a data entry form and runs various reports, which works fine.  The userform opens on the Workbook_Open event and I need to hide the workbook as the users have a habit of breaking it!

`Application.visible = false` works but, when the user opens other workbooks and closes them all down, the parent workbook of the userform also closes or hides the userform from the user and I'm not sure how to prevent it.

I've tried a number of API calls, but I keep getting the same issue where the workbook closes or ends up hidden (form included).

Has anyone ever managed to find the correct APIs that make a user form look or act as an independent application e.g. opens without the workbook being visible, allows other workbooks / programs to come to the front, allows the user to select the parent workbook / userform when needed from the taskbar, will not hide or close when the last workbook is closed.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or list the API calls I'd really appreciate it.  I'm using Excel 2013.

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: Could you use an application level add in to control this, divert the closing to stop and leave this work book open, unless the active workbook is it, so if closing the app, allow it, if closing from other workbook disallow?  In fact, thinking on it, wouldn't this be better in an addin, then it doesn't require the holding WB to be open

Comment: How about forcing this workbook to be in its own instance? Then it would be completely unaffected by whatever other Excel instances you have open. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/483382-dont-allow-another-workbook-open-instance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help and ideas, but I've settled on a much simpler (albeit not perfect) solution.  I first tried to make it an addinn as suggested by @Sun but this caused problems when opening as the very first instance of excel.

In the ThisWorkbook module I used `Public WithEvents App As Application` to create public application level event handlers.

The idea is simply to keep the Excel Workbook minimized at all times.

Followed by:

```
    Private Sub App_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

    'Check wb is workbook strThisWkBk then make sure window is minimized
        If Wb.Name = strThisWkBk Then
            With Wb.Windows.Application
                .WindowState = xlMinimized
            End With
            frmAddVouchersTab.Show vbModeless
        End If
    End Sub
```

And

```
    Private Sub App_WindowResize(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Wn As 
    'Check wb is workbook strThisWkBk then make sure window is minimized. _
        Using WindowResize to prevent user from trying to maximise

        If Wb.Name = strThisWkBk Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Speed up execution
                If Not Wn.WindowState = xlMinimized Then Wn.WindowState = xlMinimized
                frmAddVouchersTab.Show vbModeless
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

This all seems to work, but with a few niggles which I'm pretty sure I can figure out. e.g. in the With block, I'm trying to add code to size and place the minimised window just as an extra measure, but this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in the past and I think I have the answer you want.

Firstly, what I would do is to create a dummy file in place of the workbook you want to open. When that workbook opens, it should create a new instance of Excel, make it visible and open the actual workbook you want in a minimised state and then close itself.  This process will ensure that the target workbook is the only workbook open in the application.

To prevent other workbooks opening in the same application, use a Class Module in VBA.  Declare an application variable WithEvents, such as:
`Public WithEvents thisApp As Application`.

You can then capture the WorkbookOpen event (triggered when a another workbook is, you guessed it, opened) and take appropriate action.  What I tend to do it capture the path of the newly opened workbook, close it down, open yet another instance of Excel and open the workbook there.

This should make sense when you read the code:

```
Private Sub thisApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Dim xWB As Workbook, xApp As Excel.Application, xPath As String

    Application.Visible = False
    xPath = Wb.FullName
    Wb.Close
    Set xApp = New Excel.Application
    xApp.Visible = True
    xApp.Workbooks.Open xPath
    xApp.Windows(1).Activate
    Set xApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The difference is that you don't want to make the application invisible as that would mean the user could not reactivate it from the task bar.  I have had a quick play and it seems tricky to get the form to display and minimise the application when the workbook is selected from the taskbar.  (I think it is possible but it will mean hiding the form and displaying it again, which might conflict with other code.)  I would suggest adding a front page tab to your worksheet, and maybe making the data tabs invisible to the user; that should be enough to stop them breaking it.

Comment: Guys,

Thanks for looking at this for me, I really appreciate it.

I've looked at the code above and in the link posted by @Sun, and I like the idea and understand the principle, but the real life application on our systems impacts on performance.  We have work on a cloud based service which crawls along at the best of times and a number of spreadsheets that can take a while to open. So this method would end up driving our users up the wall, as they sheets open, close then open again.  It would be fine with some of our smaller workbooks, but many are unfortunately behemoths!

Comment: In that case, could you use the same approach to open the workbook with your code in another instance (and close down the current workbook) instead?  Or is that hosted on the cloud as well?

Comment: Unless there is a way to do this pragmatically, which I'm beginning to doubt, I'll have to settle for hiding (veryhidden) all the worksheets and creating a splash type background sheet.  To be honest, I'm a bit surprised that Microsoft haven't allowed for this kind of thing and come up with a native way to produce this kind of effect.

Comment: Hi @lonestorm,  thanks for the quick reply!  That may work... So using a workbook as a gateway to create another instance of excel which will hold the application.  As my userform generates excel reports on the fly, will these all have to be created in new instances of excel?  The only issue I can see is that I would have to leave the main workbook somewhere in the cloud that will still be available to everyone to access, and I'm not sure how people will treat it when they find it... I'll give it a go and see what happens

Comment: It is difficult to say what will happen to the generated reports without more detail.  If they are in the same workbook, you could program the workbook to save itself on the user's machine to preserve the generated reports.  If they are in separate workbooks, you could also save them to a client-side working directory or straight to the cloud.  If you need to store these reports for later use, I would go with the second option.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at all of these next Monday and let you know what I've found.  Thanks for all the advice, it's given me plenty to think about!  Hope you have a great weekend